# Is it possible to rename a column that contains special signs and numbers in microsoft azure in KQL?

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I started working with ***Microsoft's sentinel one***.

I'm working on gathering information from the logs that sentinel is producing.
For better readability, I want to change the names of the columns that I'm projecting, but couldn't rename a column that contained numbers and special characters.
I'm using **KQL** to gather the logs from sentinel

```
AuditLogs
| where OperationName == "Add group" or OperationName == "Delete group"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(20d)
| project TargetResources[0].displayName, OperationName, ActivityDateTime
| project-rename GroupName = TargetResources[0].displayName, Time = ActivityDateTime, Type = OperationName
```

So renaming the columns: **ActivityDateTime** & **OperationName** is working, but I get an error that says "column name expected" when trying to rename the first column. Even though it appear when running that code.

Is there a way to rename that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend operator is used to create a calculated column and new column is appended to result set. Since you just need to rename a column you can do it with **project** operator. project-rename doesn't work for expressions.

```
AuditLogs
| where OperationName == "Add group" or OperationName == "Delete group"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(20d)
| project GroupName=TargetResources[0].displayName, Type=OperationName, Time = ActivityDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

*TargetResources[0].displayName* is an expression, not a column name,  so there's nothing to rename here.

If you want to give this expression a name, you can use the *extend* operator.

`| extend GroupName = TargetResources[0].displayName`

[image: project-rename]

```
print TargetResources = dynamic([{"displayName": "Tic"}, {"displayName": "Tac"}, {"displayName": "Toe"}])
| project-rename GroupName = TargetResources[0].displayName
```

> project-rename: expression '' cannot be used as a column name

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUQhJLEpPLQlKLc4vLUpOLVawVUipzEvMzUzWiK5WSsksLshJrPRLzE1VslJQCslMVqrVUcAUT8Qhnp%20qVBuryctVo1BQlJ%20VmlyiW5QKNDxVwb0ov7QApAxoH5oLog1i9ZDMAQCWJAWVpgAAAA==)

```
print TargetResources = dynamic([{"displayName": "Tic"}, {"displayName": "Tac"}, {"displayName": "Toe"}])
| extend GroupName = TargetResources[0].displayName
```

| TargetResources | GroupName |
| --- | --- |
| [{"displayName":"Tic"},{"displayName":"Tac"},{"displayName":"Toe"}] | Tic |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUQhJLEpPLQlKLc4vLUpOLVawVUipzEvMzUzWiK5WSsksLshJrPRLzE1VslJQCslMVqrVUcAUT8Qhnp%20qVBuryctVo5BaUZKal6LgXpRfWgCSBtqDZnO0Qawekn4A0LEdV54AAAA=)

Comment: Any reason you accepted this answer and then revoked? FYI, both `project-rename` & `extend` impact only the columns they deal with, leaving all the rest of the columns As Is. `project` require you to list all the columns that you want to pass to the next stage and not only the columns that you actually want to change.